# what is this: new[] { }

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to get to grips with ASP MVC4 and I came across this within a @{...} within a .cshtml file:

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[] { 
            new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "Yes, I'll be there",  
                Value = bool.TrueString}, 
            new SelectListItem() {
                Text = "No, I can't come",  
                Value = bool.FalseString} 
        }, "Choose an option")
```

Q1) What kind of thing is this: `new[]{...}`

Q2) Am i right in saying that for razor, the stuff within the curly brackets is just any C# code.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an inline array declaration :)

Comment: @retailcoder - No, it isn't.

Comment: If you have two questions please post two questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This syntax:

```
new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" }
```

is an *implicitly typed array initializer*. The type of the array is inferred from the elements within the braces. For example, the above is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" }
```

In your case, it would be `new SelectItem[] { ... }`.

[Implicitly typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) were introduced in C# 3 (but you can use them even when targeting .NET 2.0; they're just a C# compiler feature). They're partly to support using [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), but they're useful in other situations too.

Within each element in your code, however, you've got an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), which is a way of creating an object and setting properties (or adding to collections) within a single expression. So this:

```
new SelectListItem() {
    Text = "No, I can't come",  
    Value = bool.FalseString
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
SelectListItem tmp = new SelectListItem();
tmp.Text = "No, I can't come";
tmp.Value = bool.FalseString;
```

... except it's a single expression, which is why you're able to use it within an array initializer. Again, object initializers were introduced in C# 3.

For the Razor question - I believe so, but I think the rules about when a piece of text is inferred to be "normal C#" are a bit more complicated than that (in order to be more useful).

Answer (score 6):

1) `new[] {}` creates array of items, where type is inferenced from items, in this case it's an array of `SelectListItem`.

2) Yes